# RxJS sequence equivalent to promise.then()?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I used to develop a lot with promise and now I am moving to RxJS. The doc of RxJS doesn't provide a very clear example on how to move from promise chain to observer sequence.

For example, I usually write promise chain with multiple steps, like

```
// a function that returns a promise
getPromise()
.then(function(result) {
   // do something
})
.then(function(result) {
   // do something
})
.then(function(result) {
   // do something
})
.catch(function(err) {
    // handle error
});
```

How should I rewrite this promise chain in the RxJS style?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

For data flow (equivalent to `then`):

```
Rx.Observable.fromPromise(...)
  .flatMap(function(result) {
   // do something
  })
  .flatMap(function(result) {
   // do something
  })
  .subscribe(function onNext(result) {
    // end of chain
  }, function onError(error) {
    // process the error
  });
```

A promise can be converted into an observable with [`Rx.Observable.fromPromise`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/frompromise.md).

Some promise operators have a direct translation. For instance `RSVP.all`, or `jQuery.when` can be replaced by `Rx.Observable.forkJoin`.

Keep in mind that you have a bunch of operators that allows to transform data asynchronously, and to perform tasks that you cannot or would be very hard to do with promises. Rxjs reveals all its powers with asynchronous sequences of data (sequence i.e. more than 1 asynchronous value).

For error management, the subject is a little bit more complex.

- there are [catch](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/catch.md) and [finally](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/finally.md) operators too
- `retryWhen` can also help to repeat a sequence in case of error
- you can also deal with errors in the subscriber itself with the `onError` function.

For precise semantics, have a deeper look at the documentation and examples you can find on the web, or ask specific questions here.

This would definitely be a good starting point for going deeper in error management with Rxjs : https://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/getting_started_with_rxjs/creating_and_querying_observable_sequences/error_handling.html

Comment: I always see the observable sequence ends with subscribe(). As this is only a function of observable object, is there any reason to do this? Is it the function to start the sequence?

Comment: exactly so. If there is no observers passed through subscribe, your observable will not emit any data so you won-t see any data flow.

Comment: I do recommend you to have a look at this : https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754. IT might be more palatable that the official doc.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and very helpful link :)

Comment: `Promise.then` is rather `.flatMap` than `.map`.

Comment: corrected. It escaped me that the `then` were returning promises, hence the `flatMap`

Comment: `flatMap` only works for chaining if your source emits at least one item

Comment: The chain set up in place with `flatMap` is independent of whether there are values emitted. It is like saying that a function does not work till it is applied with some parameters. `flatMap` is just a higher order stream function.

Comment: FYI this is not exactly equivalent as in the `Promise` version errors from the 3rd `then` would be caught by the `catch`. Here they're not.

Comment: You forgot to mention, that in the flatMap function, we need to return a new Observable :)

Comment: flatMap is deprecated. Why is there no up to date answers anywhere on the internet?? All I want to do is chain 2 observables the same way you can with Promises (easily) `.then(result => {})` and I can't find a single example or an explanation in plain English. Why is it so complex? This is surely the most basic use case.

Answer (score 43):

A more modern alternative:

```
import {from as fromPromise} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, flatMap} from 'rxjs/operators';

fromPromise(...).pipe(
   flatMap(result => {
       // do something
   }),
   flatMap(result => {
       // do something
   }),
   flatMap(result => {
       // do something
   }),
   catchError(error => {
       // handle error
   })
)
```

Also note that for all this to work, you need to `subscribe` to this piped `Observable` somewhere, but I assume it's handled in some other part of the application.

Comment: I'm very new to RxJS, but given that we're only dealing with an initial stream of _one_ event here, and that `mergeMap()` therefore doesn't actually have anything to _merge_, I believe we could achieve exactly the same thing in this case using `concatMap()` or `switchMap()`. Have I got this correct...?

Answer (score 13):

**Update May 2019, using RxJs 6**

Agree with the provided answers above, wished to add a concrete example with some toy data & simple promises (with setTimeout) using **RxJs v6** to add clarity.

Just update the passed id (currently hard-coded as `1`) to something that does not exist to execute the error handling logic too. Importantly, also note the use of `of` with `catchError` message.

```
import { from as fromPromise, of } from "rxjs";
import { catchError, flatMap, tap } from "rxjs/operators";

const posts = [
  { title: "I love JavaScript", author: "Wes Bos", id: 1 },
  { title: "CSS!", author: "Chris Coyier", id: 2 },
  { title: "Dev tools tricks", author: "Addy Osmani", id: 3 }
];

const authors = [
  { name: "Wes Bos", twitter: "@wesbos", bio: "Canadian Developer" },
  {
    name: "Chris Coyier",
    twitter: "@chriscoyier",
    bio: "CSS Tricks and CodePen"
  },
  { name: "Addy Osmani", twitter: "@addyosmani", bio: "Googler" }
];

function getPostById(id) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const post = posts.find(post => post.id === id);
      if (post) {
        console.log("ok, post found!");
        resolve(post);
      } else {
        reject(Error("Post not found!"));
      }
    }, 200);
  });
}

function hydrateAuthor(post) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      const authorDetails = authors.find(person => person.name === post.author);
      if (authorDetails) {
        post.author = authorDetails;
        console.log("ok, post hydrated with author info");
        resolve(post);
      } else {
        reject(Error("Author not Found!"));
      }
    }, 200);
  });
}

function dehydratePostTitle(post) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      delete post.title;
      console.log("ok, applied transformation to remove title");
      resolve(post);
    }, 200);
  });
}

// ok, here is how it looks regarding this question..
let source$ = fromPromise(getPostById(1)).pipe(
  flatMap(post => {
    return hydrateAuthor(post);
  }),
  flatMap(post => {
    return dehydratePostTitle(post);
  }),
  catchError(error => of(`Caught error: ${error}`))
);

source$.subscribe(console.log);
```

Output Data:

```
ok, post found!
ok, post hydrated with author info
ok, applied transformation to remove title
{ author:
   { name: 'Wes Bos',
     twitter: '@wesbos',
     bio: 'Canadian Developer' },
  id: 1 }
```

The key part, is equivalent to the following using plain promise control flow:

```
getPostById(1)
  .then(post => {
    return hydrateAuthor(post);
  })
  .then(post => {
    return dehydratePostTitle(post);
  })
  .then(author => {
    console.log(author);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: Perfect answer, but now flatMap is depricated! What's the new method?

Comment: flatMap -> mergeMap

Comment: this was incredibly helpful, thank you

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you mean consuming the values, in which case you use sbuscribe i.e.

```
const arrObservable = from([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]);
arrObservable.subscribe(number => console.log(num) );
```

Additionally, you can just turn the observable to a promise using toPromise() as shown:

```
arrObservable.toPromise().then()
```

Comment: Do not convert observable into promise. It works, but it's bad desing.

Answer (score 0):

if `getPromise` function is in a middle of a stream pipe you should simple wrap it into one of functions `mergeMap`, `switchMap` or `concatMap` (usually `mergeMap`):

```
stream$.pipe(
   mergeMap(data => getPromise(data)),
   filter(...),
   map(...)
 ).subscribe(...);
```

if you want to start your stream with `getPromise()` then wrap it into `from` function:

```
import {from} from 'rxjs';

from(getPromise()).pipe(
   filter(...)
   map(...)
).subscribe(...);
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as i just found out, if you return a result in a flatMap, it converts it to an Array, even if you returned a string.

But if you return an Observable, that observable can return a string;

Answer (score 0):

This is how I did it.

**Previously**

```
  public fetchContacts(onCompleteFn: (response: gapi.client.Response<gapi.client.people.ListConnectionsResponse>) => void) {
    const request = gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
      resourceName: 'people/me',
      pageSize: 100,
      personFields: 'phoneNumbers,organizations,emailAddresses,names'
    }).then(response => {
      onCompleteFn(response as gapi.client.Response<gapi.client.people.ListConnectionsResponse>);
    });
  }

// caller:

  this.gapi.fetchContacts((rsp: gapi.client.Response<gapi.client.people.ListConnectionsResponse>) => {
      // handle rsp;
  });
```

**After(ly?)**

```
public fetchContacts(): Observable<gapi.client.Response<gapi.client.people.ListConnectionsResponse>> {
    return from(
      new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
          resourceName: 'people/me',
          pageSize: 100,
          personFields: 'phoneNumbers,organizations,emailAddresses,names'
        }).then(result => {
          resolve(result);
        });
      })
    ).pipe(map((result: gapi.client.Response<gapi.client.people.ListConnectionsResponse>) => {
      return result; //map is not really required if you not changing anything in the response. you can just return the from() and caller would subscribe to it.
    }));
  }

// caller

this.gapi.fetchContacts().subscribe(((rsp: gapi.client.Response<gapi.client.people.ListConnectionsResponse>) => {
  // handle rsp
}), (error) => {
  // handle error
});
```

Comment: **side effect**: change detection also started to work after converting callback into  _observable_.

Answer (score -1):

**RxJS sequence equivalent to promise.then()?**

For example

```
function getdata1 (argument) {
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

    function getdata2 (argument) {
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    }

    getdata1.subscribe((data1: any) => {
        console.log("got data one. get data 2 now");
        getdata2.subscribe((data2: any) => {
            console.log("got data one and two here");
        });
    });
```