# Chaining Observables in RxJS

Tags: javascript, promise, reactive-programming, rxjs, rxjs5

I'm learning RxJS and Angular 2. Let's say I have a promise chain with multiple async function calls which depend on the previous one's result which looks like:

```
var promiseChain = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    resolve(1);
  }, 1000);
}).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(result + 2);
    }, 1000);
  });
}).then((result) => {
  console.log(result);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(result + 3);
        }, 1000);
  });
});

promiseChain.then((finalResult) => {
  console.log(finalResult);
});
```

My attempts at doing the same solely using RxJS without the use of promises produced the following:

```
var observableChain = Observable.create((observer) => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    observer.next(1);
    observer.complete();
  }, 1000);
}).flatMap((result) => {
  console.log(result);

  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next(result + 2);
      observer.complete()
    }, 1000);
  });
}).flatMap((result) => {
  console.log(result);

  return Observable.create((observer) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      observer.next(result + 3);
      observer.complete()
    }, 1000);
  });
});

observableChain.subscribe((finalResult) => {
  console.log(finalResult);
});
```

It yields the same output as the promise chain. My questions are

1. Am I doing this right? Are there any RxJS related improvements that I can make to the above code
2. How do I get this observable chain to execute repeatedly? i.e. Adding another subscription at the end just produces an additional 6 though I expect it to print 1, 3 and 6.

   observableChain.subscribe((finalResult) => {
     console.log(finalResult);
   });

   observableChain.subscribe((finalResult) => {
     console.log(finalResult);
   });

   1
   3
   6
   6

Comment: Have put a working example of chaining promises using rxjs6 here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55991374/1882064

Answer (score 62, accepted):

About promise composition vs. Rxjs, as this is a frequently asked question, you can refer to a number of previously asked questions on SO, among which :

- [How to do the chain sequence in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748241/how-to-do-the-chain-sequence-in-rxjs/37748799#37748799)
- [RxJS Promise Composition (passing data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701304/rxjs-promise-composition-passing-data/34701912#34701912)
- [RxJS sequence equvalent to promise.then()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523338/could-anyone-give-me-a-sample-of-rxjs-sequence-equvalent-to-promise-then)

Basically, `flatMap` is the equivalent of `Promise.then`.

For your second question, do you want to replay values already emitted, or do you want to process new values as they arrive? In the first case, check the `publishReplay` operator. In the second case, standard subscription is enough. However you might need to be aware of the cold. vs. hot dichotomy depending on your source (cf. [Hot and Cold observables : are there 'hot' and 'cold' operators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32190445/hot-and-cold-observables-are-there-hot-and-cold-operators) for an illustrated explanation of the concept)

Comment: flatMap is deprecated in RXJs 6+, please use mergeMap instead

Comment: .pipe(mergeMap(() => forkJoin({first: first$, second: second$,}))); if you want to start more than one.

Answer (score 1):

**Example for clarification:**

Top of pipe can emit n values (this answers "How do I get this observable chain to execute repeatedly"), but subsequent chained streams emit one value (hence mimicing promises).

```
// Emit three values into the top of this pipe
const topOfPipe = of<string>('chaining', 'some', 'observables');

// If any of the chained observables emit more than 1 value
// then don't use this unless you understand what is going to happen.
const firstObservablePipe = of(1); 
const secondObservablePipe = of(2);
const thirdObservablePipe = of(3);
const fourthObservablePipe = of(4);

const addToPreviousStream = (previous) => map(current => previous + current);
const first = (one) => firstObservablePipe.pipe(addToPreviousStream(one));
const second = (two) => secondObservablePipe.pipe(addToPreviousStream(two));
const third = (three) => thirdObservablePipe.pipe(addToPreviousStream(three));
const fourth = (four) => fourthObservablePipe.pipe(addToPreviousStream(four));

topOfPipe.pipe(
  mergeMap(first),
  mergeMap(second),
  mergeMap(third),
  mergeMap(fourth),
).subscribe(console.log);

// Output: chaining1234 some1234 observables1234
```

You could also use concatMap or switchMap. They all have subtle differences. See rxjs docs to understand.

mergeMap:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap

concatMap:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap

switchMap:
https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap