# How to groupBy data properly when using HTTP response?

Tags: json, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

here is what iam trying to achieve, i want to groupBy product_category in Array JSON but my array JSON is nested, which looks like this :

```
[
    {
        "result": "success",
        "data": [
            {
                "product_id": 17,
                "product_name": "KLO-101",
                "parent_category": "Juicer"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 42,
                "product_name": "CRO-528",
                "parent_category": "Vacuum Cleaner"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 15,
                "product_name": "KLC-127",
                "parent_category": "Juicer"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 41,
                "product_name": "CRO-3120-WD",
                "parent_category": "Vacuum Cleaner"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

what the json i want to build is, below is JSON illustration that i made write manually :

```
[{
    'Vacuum Cleaner' : 
           [{
                "product_id": 41,
                "product_name": "CRO-3120-WD",
                "parent_category": "Vacuum Cleaner"
            },
            {
                "product_id": 42,
                "product_name": "CRO-528",
                "parent_category": "Vacuum Cleaner"
            }],
   'Juicer' : 
            [{
                "product_id": 17,
                "product_name": "KLO-101",
                "parent_category": "Juicer"
                 },
            {
                "product_id": 15,
                "product_name": "KLC-127",
                "parent_category": "Juicer"
            }]
}]
```

from what i read, in stackoverflow somewhere its written that JSON data can be grouped with using map().groupBy() which is in my code and it looks like this :

app.service.ts :

```
getProductService(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http
        .post(global.server + "/product", this.options)
        .map(a=> a.json().data)
        .groupBy(
            a=>a.parent_category,
            a=>a
        )
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

and here is my app.component.ts :

```
  getProduct() {
    this.appService.getProductService().subscribe(
      result => {
        console.log(result);
        this.dataProduct = result[0].data;
      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
  }
```

but i get an error, 'a is undefined' how to use `.groupBy()`   properly? angular version that i use is angular 4

UPDATE!!!

here is my code after i updated with martin answer, but still i can't figure it out, since i have to pull the JSON data from REST API, the code won't detect the 'parent_category', below is my code

app.component.ts

```
dataProduct : any;

      getProduct() {
        this.appService.getProductService().subscribe(
          result => {
            this.dataProduct = result[0].data;
          },
          error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );

        Observable.of(this.dataProduct)
          .mergeMap(array => array) // unpack into single emissionns (or mergeAll() but it's broken in RxJS 5.4)
          .groupBy(item => item.parent_category)
          .mergeMap(observable => observable
            .toArray()
            .map(results => (this.dataProduct = { [results[0].parent_category]: results }))
          )
          .toArray()
          .subscribe(console.log);

          console.log(JSON.stringify(this.dataProduct));
      }
```

i got error

> [ts] Property 'parent_category' does not exist on type '{}'

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think i have to implement lodash since i really confuse about observeable way, i really can't understand it, so i decided to use lodash way, it's so simple, so here is my code how to group the JSON data properly. i have to import lodash which is already include in my project, if you dont have lodash in your node_modules, you have to npm install it

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

  getProduct() {
    this.appService.getProductService().subscribe(
      result => {
        this.dataTest = result;

        let datas = this.dataTest;

        this.dataProduct = _(datas)
        .groupBy(data => data.parent_category)
        .map((datas, category) => ({ category, datas }))
        .value();

      },
      error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
    );
```

and i just need to loop the JSON data inside "datas" with *ngFor in HTML

Comment: Hey, found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771855/chaining-observables-in-rxjs. works fine.

Answer (score 0):

In angular 1 this is the way i do

```
var inputdata = [
{
    "result": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "product_id": 17,
            "product_name": "KLO-101",
            "parent_category": "Juicer"
        },
        {
            "product_id": 42,
            "product_name": "CRO-528",
            "parent_category": "Vacuum Cleaner"
        },
        {
            "product_id": 15,
            "product_name": "KLC-127",
            "parent_category": "Juicer"
        },
        {
            "product_id": 41,
            "product_name": "CRO-3120-WD",
            "parent_category": "Vacuum Cleaner"
        }
    ]
}];

var grouped = _(inputdata[0].data).groupBy(function (d) {
    return d.parent_category;
});

var finalArray = _.mapObject(grouped, function (value, key) {
    return value;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupBy` is an RxJS operator that emits Observables. In other words it returns an Observable emitting other Observables (so called "higher-order Observable"). It would be easier for you to use just `map()` and transform data there but if you want to go with `groupBy` you'll need to do some adjustments to make sure the inner Observable completes before you pass it to the resulting object:

```
const data = [
    {
        "product_id": 17,
        "product_name": "KLO-101",
        "parent_category": "Juicer"
    },
    {
        "product_id": 42,
        "product_name": "CRO-528",
        "parent_category": "Vacuum Cleaner"
    },
    {
        "product_id": 15,
        "product_name": "KLC-127",
        "parent_category": "Juicer"
    },
    {
        "product_id": 41,
        "product_name": "CRO-3120-WD",
        "parent_category": "Vacuum Cleaner"
    }
];

Observable.of(data)
    .mergeMap(array => array) // unpack into single emissionns (or mergeAll() but it's broken in RxJS 5.4)
    .groupBy(item => item.parent_category)
    .mergeMap(observable => observable
        .toArray()
        .map(results => ({ [results[0].parent_category] : results }))
    )
    .toArray()
    .subscribe(console.log);
```

Prints:

```
[ { Juicer: [ { product_id: 17,
       product_name: 'KLO-101',
       parent_category: 'Juicer' },
     { product_id: 15,
       product_name: 'KLC-127',
       parent_category: 'Juicer' } ] },
  { 'Vacuum Cleaner': [ { product_id: 42,
       product_name: 'CRO-528',
       parent_category: 'Vacuum Cleaner' },
     { product_id: 41,
       product_name: 'CRO-3120-WD',
       parent_category: 'Vacuum Cleaner' } ] 
} ]
```

Comment: i am sorry, can you be more specific? where should i put the Observeable.of code? in my app.component.ts or app.service.ts? i should put it inside the this.http.post().map and continue here right?

Comment: `Observable.of(data)` is instead of your `this.http.post(global.server + "/product", this.options).map(a=> a.json().data)`

Comment: hi martin, how do i print the data in HTML where should i set the variable? i usually print the data in HTML is set the value into variable ex : this.dataTest = result[0].data

Comment: @KeVin I have no idea how you want to print it in you HTML so I can't help you with it.

Comment: i just want to print the json data just like this {{ dataTest | json }} and can you help me with the error? i updated my question for the error i got with following your code

Comment: If you want have proper types or interfaces you can use `item['parent_category']` notation.