# Chaining HttpClient calls in Angular 6

Tags: rxjs, angular6

I think I have read 100+ posts on the topic, and I still cannot figure out how to chain two HttpClient calls using rxjs in Angular 6.

Let's say I have a service with that signature:

```
  GeoService {
      getState(): Observable<string> {
          return this.http.get<string>(stateURL);
      }
      getCities(state: string): Observable<string[]> {
          return this.http.get<string[]>(citiesURL + state);
      }
   }
```

I can't for the life of me figure out how to obtain both the state and the corresponding list of cities in my component:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, flatMap, mergeMap, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

...

 ngOnInit() {

      this.svc.getState().
        pipe(map((state) => {
            this.state = state;
            return this.svc.getCities(state);
          }),
          mergeMap((cities) => this.cities = cities))
        ).
        subscribe(console.log('done'));
```

The code above in one of my 20 random attempts at combining pipe/map/mergeMap/subscribe in every way I could think of... a working example would be really really appreciated :)

Thanks!

Edit: None of the "possible duplicate" posts contain an actual example that works

Comment: you could chain them by putting the second (and third and so on) call within the res part (completion if you dont need the res value) of the subscribe to the previous call. eg: `this.svc.getState().subscribe(res=>{this.svc.getCities(res).subscribe(res=>{},err=>{},()=>{})},err=>{},()=>{})`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chaining Observables in RxJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771855/chaining-observables-in-rxjs)

Comment: @ggradnig i wouldnt say so, you can do it from the subscribe part of the http call

Comment: `this.svc.getState().pipe(mergeMap(state => this.svc. getCities(state))).subscribe(...)`

Comment: @martin you need to subscribe to the `getCities()` call else it wont actually make the http call

Comment: @mast3rd3mon you could, but thinking a little bit further, it is well possible that we want to express the chained http calls as **one** Observable (i.e. for use of Angular Async Pipe).

Comment: @ggradnig why complicate it when its a simple answer?

Comment: what's complicated about `mergeMap` ?

Comment: @mast3rd3mon No, that's what `mergeMap` does already. You need just one `subscribe` call at the end of the chain

Comment: his isnt complicated, its just missing out a subscribe call which will mean it will fail, its over complicated to use flatmaps, mergemaps, maps, etc when they arent necessary

Comment: mergemap subscribes internally to the inner observable, there is no "missing" subscribe call. also, you said it isn't complicated and it is complicated in the same sentence.

Comment: if you read it, i said his suggestion isnt complicated, but your recommendation of a dupe and your answer both over complicate what is a simple answer

Comment: martin's suggestion and my answer are de facto identical. his just leaves out the state changes that OP intended to do regardless of how the chaining was implemented.

Comment: mast3rd3mon, ggradnig and martin are not overcomplicating, but fixing your suggestion into something acceptable. You should never ever nest subscriptions. Instead of arguing, you should keep an open mind and you might learn something.

Comment: Sorry if my last comment was a bit harsh. But you should indeed use switchMap, mergeMap or one of its variants. Nested subscriptions are always avoidable, and you should avoid them. Keep in mind that every subscription needs an unsubscribe. Try to manage that when nesting subscriptions ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
this.svc.getState().pipe(
     tap(state=>this.state=state),
     switchMap(this.svc.getCities))
.subscribe(cities=>{
    //got the cities
})
```

the map operator is here to transform the emited value, but the tap operator is used to do something without modifying emited value of the observable.

*note that switchMap(this.svc.getCities) is equivalent to switchMap(state=>this.svc.getCities(state)*

Comment: You are assigning a global variable in an rxjs operator. That is a bit of an anti-pattern ...

Comment: a global valiable ? where ?

Comment: this.state? Your rxjs operators should ideally use pure functions.

Comment: ok but the tap ( new version of "do" ) operator is made for side-effect
https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/tap

Comment: Correct. But its still an anti-pattern ;) And in this case, is easily solved using a standard map operator.

Comment: @Davy its only global locally to that file (unless that file is accessed by any other files), not global to the project

Answer (score 2):

The 21st attempt would have been correct ;-)

```
this.svc.getState().
    pipe(mergeMap((state) => {
        this.state = state;
        return this.svc.getCities(state);
    }),
    tap((cities) => this.cities = cities)))
.subscribe(() => console.log('done'));
```

The chained Observable goes inside `mergeMap`. You can think of it as:

> First, **map** the incoming notifaction to an Observable, then **merge** the resulting "inner" Observable into the "outer" Observable

Also, use `tap` instead of `map` if you intend to change an outside state.

Comment: Thanks, I tested our solution and it works. I accepted Kevins' answer since it is simpler, and it doesn't change state from inside mergeMap.

Answer (score 2):

You were almost there:

```
    this.svc.getState().
        pipe(
            mergeMap((state) => {
                return this.svc.getCities(state).pipe(map(cities => {
                    return { state: state, cities: cities }
                }));
            }),
        ).subscribe(stateAndCities => console.log(stateAndCities));
```

I advise you to read this article:

https://blog.strongbrew.io/rxjs-best-practices-in-angular/#using-pure-functions

It also explains why you shouldnt interact with global variables in rxjs operators.

Comment: Thanks, tested and it works. I accepted Kevin's answer since it doesn't involve an intermediate object.

Comment: I do understand your point about pure functions, but I don't like having to aggregate into a meaningless object just to carry results to the end of the pipe.
A pattern that would be natural to me would be:
var response = this.svc.getState();
response.subscribe(state => this.state = state);
response.pipe(map(state => getProviders(state))).subscribe(cities => ...);
Pseudo-code, and I'm so fed up with that API that I don't have the courage to test it...

Comment: That would work, but your response object would have to be a ReplaySubject (or an Observable with publishReplay() applied)