# Angular subscribe to chain observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a service that is to chain a set of http requests and return a list of products.
This is what I have so far:

```
listForDisplay(categoryId: string): Observable<any[]> {
    if (!categoryId) return of([]);
    return this.listFields(categoryId);
}

private listFields(categoryId: string): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.fieldService.list(categoryId, true).pipe(
        flatMap((fields: Field[]) => {
            if (!fields) return of([]);
            return this.listProducts(categoryId, fields);
        }),
    );
}

private listProducts(categoryId: string, fields: Field[]): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.productService.listSpecificationProducts(categoryId).pipe(
        flatMap((products: any[]) => {
            if (!products) return of([]);
            return this.mapVisibleFields(fields, products);
        }),
    );
}

private mapVisibleFields(fields: Field[], products: any[]): any[] {
    console.log(products);
    return this.productModelService.mapProductsWithSpecificationFields(fields, products);
}
```

In my controller I call this:

```
private getCategory() {
    this.selectorSubscription = this.selectorService.category.subscribe(categoryId => {
        this.products = [];
        this.specificationService.listForDisplay(categoryId).subscribe((products: any[]) => {
            console.log(products);
            this.products = products;
        });
    });
}
```

The problem is that the `console.log` in the first part returns an array.
The `console.log` in the controller only returns a single item....

Like this:

[image]

I am clearly doing something wrong.
Can anyone help?

Comment: What does `this.productModelService.mapProductsWithSpecificationFields` do

Comment: Removes properties from the product model that I don't want to display in a table. I have tried commenting that line our and just returning the products, it still has the same issue as above

Comment: @r3plica Can you show http requests? Element Inspector (network)

Answer (score 0):

As per rxjs [documentation](http://Projects%20each%20source%20value%20to%20an%20Observable%20which%20is%20merged%20in%20the%20output%20Observable.), flatMap

> Projects each source value to an Observable which is merged in the
>   output Observable.

This is why your subscribe is being called multiple times with each value coming one at a time. Are you sure you need flatMap? It seems from what you are trying to do, [map](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/map) would is more appropriate.

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't work. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: Type 'Observable<any[] | Observable<any[]>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<any[]>'.
  Type 'any[] | Observable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.
    Type 'Observable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'any[]'.

Comment: this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37771855/chaining-observables-in-rxjs says flatMap is like promise.then, which is what I am trying to do. I want the last value from all the chains

Comment: The typing issue is because you are returning different types from the same function. For example, return of([]) gives Observable<any[]>, but mapVisibileFields returns just any[];

I suggest change the return types to just `any` for the time being and see if map works.

Comment: `map` is also like a promise.then. `flatMap` just flattens your array and converts all the items into multiple observables. You don't need everything to be a separate observable, you just want the final list of products, which is what map will give you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205100/discussion-between-shahzad-b-and-r3plica).