# Wait for inner subscriptions inside map?

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

When I try to subscribe inside `map` function, the observable doesn't wait for inner subscriptions to execute.

I have the folowwing :

```
        return this.http.get(url).map((project)=>{       
             // replace pilot id by pilot object 
             this.UserService.retrieveObject(project.pilot).subscribe(pilot => { 
                 project.pilot = pilot,
             })

             //replace owner id by owner object
             this.UserService.retrieveObject(project.owner).subscribe(owner => { 
                 project.owner = owner,
             })
             return project;
         });
```

the returning `project` object contains owner, and pilot ids instead of objects because it doesn't wait for subscriptions.

How to make so that observable wait for all inner subscriptions to finish ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788163/how-to-make-nested-observable-calls-in-angular2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to refactor this significantly.

You can use `forkJoin` to wait for both Observables to complete and then use its "projection" function to update `project` object:

```
return this.http.get(url)
    .mergeMap(project => Observable.forkJoin(
        this.UserService.retrieveObject(project.pilot),
        this.UserService.retrieveObject(project.owner),
        (pilot, owner) => {
            project.pilot = pilot;
            project.owner = owner
            return project;
        }
    ));
```

Comment: One thing worth pointing out is the error behavior: if either sub-request fails, the overall chain will fail.

Comment: I love you man, I would never guess the role of the last forkJoin parameter without your answer. TY VM

Comment: @IngoBürk How to make so that it executes even if one request fail ?

Comment: You can add a `.catch(…)` to the requests inside `forkJoin` to handle errors in individual sub-requests.