# How to chain Observable.subscribe calling efficiently in Angular 7?

Tags: angular, observable, chaining

For a project I'm working on, my team and I are using Angular 7.  We're kind of new to Angular 7, so we're all cooperatively learning about how some things work, as compared to AngularJS, which we've used for a few years.

I was reading some recommendations on [anti-patterns in Observables](https://medium.com/@paynoattn/3-common-mistakes-i-see-people-use-in-rx-and-the-observable-pattern-ba55fee3d031), and noticed an example like the following:

```
this.http.get<MyRadModel>(`api/example/rad/${this.someId}`)
  .mergeMap(radResult => {
    // ... Instructions ...
    return this.http.get<SomeOtherModel>(`api/example/other/${radResult.something}`)
  })
  .subscribe(otherResult => {
    // ... Chained instructions! ...
  });
```

Needless to say, you have to use `.pipe()` to do this in Angular 6+ due to changes in RxJS, so actually applying this looks a little different...

```
this.http.get<MyRadModel>(`api/example/rad/${this.someId}`)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(radResult => {
      // ... Instructions ...

      // Problem #1: 'Property something does not exist on radResult'.
      // ... It actually *does*.
      return this.http.get<SomeOtherModel>(`api/example/other/${radResult.something}`);
    }
  )
  .subscribe(otherResult => {
    // ... Chained instructions ...
  });
```

One problem I noticed is that it seems that the recommended way of chaining `Observables` doesn't let us use models when we're using `mergeMap`.  Further, as a side note, using typing annotation:

```
.pipe(
  mergeMap(radResult: MyRadModel => {
    // Problem #2: 'Cannot find name radResult.'
  })
)
```

...Causes errors too.

**Question:** What's a good way to chain `Observables` in Angular 7, that allows me type safety and access to the properties of things that I need to use in the interstitial `Observable.subscribe` calls that seem to be happening?  As noted, a number of earlier Angular tutorials and recommendations on best practices seem broken due to change in RxJS.

**Side note:** Bear in mind that I'm a newcomer to the RxJS way of doing things; I'm an AngularJS veteran.  I know just enough about RxJS to know I know little.  It's possible that I'm applying the wrong technique to chaining `Observable.subscribe` calls.

Comment: Is the 3rd snippet what you're actually using or a pseudo example?  You need parenthesis around the callback arg when typed. `mergeMap( (radResult: MyRadModel) => ....`

Comment: As @Phix mentioned, you have to enclose args in a parenthesis when your args are typed or if you have multiple args (typed or non typed).

Comment: Can you try using `concatMap` instead?  It preserves order while `mergeMap` doesn't.

Comment: @Phix et al - On the parentheses: "Oops."  I forgot that, my bad.  That helps, actually.  Good ol' ID-10T error on my part. :(

Comment: You might take a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788163/how-to-make-nested-observable-calls-in-angular2 which uses flatMap()