# Angular 7 - nesting Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have an Angular route which uses a parameter `:client_name`, and a service with method `getClientDetails(client_name)` to fetch data from an HTTP API based on `:client_name`. Both are Observable methods working on their own, but when I combine the 2 observables then the API call runs before the params has been fetched (client_name is undefined):

```
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
  this.client_name = params['client_name'];
  this.dataService.getClientDetails(this.client_name).subscribe(
    clientdata => {
      this.client = clientdata;
      console.log(clientdata);
    });
```

How can I chain both observables so the API only runs once the `:client_name` is returned?

Comment: Hmm.. so the `getClientDetails` method will only run if `params['client_name']` is defined?

Comment: @wentjun correct.

Comment: Ok. And what will happen if it is undefined? Is there any specific behaviour you want to trigger?

Comment: you can look into this link:                                                                                     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788163/how-to-make-nested-observable-calls-in-angular2

Comment: @wentjun The API call should only run once params['client_name'] is resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can make use of pipeable RxJS operators for this scenario.

First, we can use RxJS's [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html) to map over the observable values from `route` into an inner observable. If `params` and `params['client_name']` are defined, we assign `params['client_name']` to the `client_name` property, which is similar to your initial code. Then, we call the `getClientDetails()` method from `dataService`. If the `params` do not exist, we convert `null` into an observable, and return it.

Subsequently, the observables are returned in `.subscribe()` block. From there, we can assign the response to the `client` property.

```
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
.
.
this.route.params.pipe(
  mergeMap(params => {
    if (params && params['client_name']) {
      this.client_name = params['client_name'];
      return this.dataService.getClientDetails(this.client_name);
    } else {
      return of(null)
    }
  })
).subscribe(response => {
  // handle the rest
  this.client = response;
})
```

Comment: If I use next, error and complete structure, can we put the second subscribe into the complete block rather than `mergeMap`?

Comment: @Bigeyes Hmm.. I wouldn't recommend you to do that. You can use `mergeMap` to chain the nested operations. The `complete` callback should only be used to handle any logic regarding the completion of execution of that block of code!

Comment: All right. Actually I have several http requests that should be in order. I heard about Contact in RxJS, can we use it to chain them together?

Comment: @Bigeyes `mergeMap`, and `concat`, would both work. Depending on the exact usage, you might want to use `combineLatest` or `forkJoin too`! If you still need help with that, maybe you can give me more context on the exact usage?

Comment: Thank you for the nice reply. For example, I have two web api calls. The first one is `http get`, Once I get the returned data, I want to make the second `http post` service call. So I want to chain them together.

Comment: @Bigeyes Hmm.. In that case, it would really depend on the details. For instance, if the first API request (with http get) returns a set of data, and that data is required to call the subsequent API request (http post), you will need to use `mergeMap()`