# how to do nested http calls in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a parent observable and two child observables who are getting the `trialId` from parent response and do http calls on their own. I tried to use `mergeMap` but it gives me error that it's not a function. How could I do this ?

```
private _trialListPoll$ = timer(0, this.listRequestInterval).pipe(

    this.trialDataService.getTrailForPatient(this.patientId).mergeMap(
      (data) => {
        if (data.result.length > 0) {
          const trial = data.result[0] as TrialPhase;
          this.trialId = trial.trialId;
          this.trialStartDate = trial.startDate;
          this.trialEndDate = trial.endDate;
          this.trialData$.next(data.result[0]);
          this.loadDailyQuestionaireAnswerData(this.trialId); // child which makes http call and being subscribed somewhere
          this.loadStartEndQuestionaireData(this.trialId); // child which makes http call and being subscribed somewhere
        } else {
          this.trialStartDate = undefined;
          this.trialEndDate = undefined;
          this.trialData$.next(undefined);
        }
        this.isQuestionnaireInDateRange();
        this.isLoadingTrial$.next(false);
      }
    ),share());
```

Comment: You should `pipe(mergeMap))`. Only `pipe` exists as a function on Observable.

Comment: ah ok ,but now it doesnt work at all... i guess type problem i have here

Comment: For `mergeMap` you need to return an observable. I think you should just replace `mergeMap` with `tap` and it will work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 7 - nesting Observables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56572705/angular-7-nesting-observables)

Comment: Could you work up a stackblitz of your issue?

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would do a nested call like this:

```
  todosForUser$ = this.http.get<User>(`${this.userUrl}/${this.userName}`)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(user =>
        this.http.get<ToDo[]>(`${this.todoUrl}?userId=${user.id}`)
      )
    );
```

In this example, we get the user by userName, then use the `switchMap` to get the related data using the retrieved user's id.

For multiple requests, you can do something like this:

**Observable**

```
  dataForUser$ = this.http.get<User>(`${this.userUrl}/${this.userName}`)
    .pipe(
      switchMap(user =>
        combineLatest([
          of(user),
          this.http.get<ToDo[]>(`${this.todoUrl}?userId=${user.id}`),
          this.http.get<Post[]>(`${this.postUrl}?userId=${user.id}`)
        ])
      ),
      map(([user, todos, posts]) => ({
        name: user.name,
        todos: todos,
        posts: posts
      }) as UserData)
    );
```

**Interface for the set of data**

```
export interface UserData {
  name: string;
  posts: Post[];
  todos: ToDo[];
}
```

This code retrieves the first set of data (so we have the userId from the username), then uses `combineLatest` to combine the latest values from each of the streams.

I have a stackblitz example here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-todos-deborahk

Hope this helps.