# How to cancel all pending Http request before call new Http request in angular 6

Tags: angular, request, abort

I am working in one angular project that have call API in a sequence and API response is stored in single global variable.

My API flow is look like below : 
[image]

Explaination :

1. User click on first request button, then first request is send to server.
2. Before display data of first request in html, user click on another button and make second API request.
3. here response of first request not returned by server yet and make another request.
4. after that, response of second request is occur first.
5. then result of first request is occur.
6. At that time, all result will merge. but expected output is like this :
7. cancel first request and only display result of second request.

Is there any way to cancel all pending request first then make another request.
Please help me.

Comment: why don't you use spinner with backdrop so that user is bound to wait for 1st request response before clicking second button

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40788163/how-to-make-nested-observable-calls-in-angular2

Comment: look at switchMap

Comment: One way of achieving it by using rxjs `switchMap` operator. https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can handle this, with any of the followings :

a) Better approach would be to use a spinner with overlay, since you must make the user aware that he has already triggered the request and is awaiting for the response

b) With Observables you can use "SwitchMap" to cancel pending subscriptions, refer: 
[SwitchMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/switchmap.html)

c) Inside your interceptor, store all incoming requests as key-value pair, if any request with same key comes again, simply reject it, however this will cancel the subsequent similar requests.

Cheers (y)

Comment: Thank you for reply. I am implement takeUntil pipe in http request suggested by : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46068908/how-to-cancel-unsubscribe-all-pending-http-requests-angular-4
I can't use first method of overlay because I don't want to block user.

Comment: i would prefer, switchmap over takeUnitl since apart from the overheads in takeUntil, you might run in issues like leaks etc, whereas switchMap specifically designed to serve this purpose to work only on one subscription and cancel others.

Comment: sorry for late reply, I  will try to use switchmap.