# Joining two observables based on id

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs6

I have two api calls, one for getting all categories and another to get the posts. In posts api, I'm getting the categories ids, I just need to call the categories and get the categories name and add the name instead of ids in the post calls. I know it's not recommended to use nested api calls, so I used `flatMap` but have no idea how to implement it.

**categories**

```
[
  {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "Angular",
    "slug": "angular",
    "parent": 4
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Tutorial",
    "slug": "tutorial",
    "parent": 0
  }
]
```

**posts**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "categories": [
      5,
      4
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "categories": [
      5
    ]
  }
]
```

**code**

```
this.blogService.getCategories()
  .pipe(
  flatMap((categories: BlogCategoryModel[]) => {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(categories)); // I think I have to do logic here
    return this.blogService.getPosts();
  })
).subscribe(posts => console.log(JSON.stringify(posts)));
```

**expected result**

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "categories": [
      "Angular",
      "Tutorial"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "categories": [
      "Angular"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do the chain sequence in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748241/how-to-do-the-chain-sequence-in-rxjs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just `forkJoin` and no `mergeMap`/`flatMap`:

```
forkJoin([
  this.blogService.getCategories(),
  this.blogService.getPosts(),
]).pipe(
  map(([categories, posts]) => {
    posts.forEach(post => {
      // Replace category ids with their names from `categories` array
    });
    return posts;
  })
).subscribe(posts => ...);
```

Comment: This looks promising, but is there any way to avoid `forEach`?

Comment: You can use `map` or whatever you want. Or you wanted to make each post a separate emission?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mergeMap](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html)

Try like this:

```
var result = this.blogService.getCategories().pipe(
  mergeMap(value =>  this.getPosts(value[0].id)))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Observable can offer a ton of method and tools to create beautiful and readable pipelines. Here is an example :

```
// my.service.ts
getData1(): Observable {
  return this.httpClient.get();
}

getData2(): Observable {
  return this.httpClient.post();
}

getData3(): Observable {
  return this.httpClient.get();
}
```

```
my.component.ts

ngOnInit() {
  this.myService.getData1().pipe(
    map(data => {
      // do what you want with the request answer
      data.id += 1;
      return data;
    }),
    // Pass the modified data and return the Observable for the getData2 request
    switchMap(data => this.myService.getData2(data)),
    // RxJs have a ton of feature to let you play with the data and the pipeline
    // This will wait for 2000ms
    delay(2000),
    // Pass the data returns by getData2 requests to the method getData3
    switchMap(data => this.myService.getData3(data)),
  ).subscribe(
    data => console.log(data); // The result of your pipeline
  )
}
```

What happen here:

1. getData1() is call and will return an Observable of our HttpRequest
2. We modify the result of the request made before (increment the id)
3. We use the modified result to call getData2 which returns an Observable of the request
4. We wait 2000ms to continue
5. We use the result of getData2 request to call getData3
6. We subscribe to this pipeline to get the final result

> If you do not subscribe to a pipeline, it will never be triggered

RxJs is a really huge and nice library to play with data, but too much people do not really not how to use it well.

To use the library you just have one thing to follow:

- **Never put an Observable inside an Observable**

About chaining Rxjs, as this is a frequently asked question, you can refer to a number of previously asked questions on SO, among which :

- [How to do the chain sequence in rxjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748241/how-to-do-the-chain-sequence-in-rxjs/37748799#37748799)
- [RxJS Promise Composition (passing data)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34701304/rxjs-promise-composition-passing-data/34701912#34701912)
- [RxJS sequence equivalent to promise.then()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34523338/could-anyone-give-me-a-sample-of-rxjs-sequence-equvalent-to-promise-then)